Monetizing problem solving for a recent release of Linux flavor
During my work as a software engineer I have encountered a serious issue concerning usage of security hardware device and some software packages.The issue is that after a recent upgrade of Linux flavor , the previously working link of device->packages->usage has been broken and an open-source project has not resolved the issue nor anyone succeeded (or tried) to resolve the issue ,probably because solving this issue is out of scope of competence for most companies and they are reluctant to spend resources to resolve it.
I believe it would take me 3 months of work ,give or take , to resolve the issue.
The question is - how would I be able to monetize it?
I mean , I could fork the open-source project , post a solution and then what ?
I would probably spend a significant time resolving bugs,adding new feature,etc.
So what's in it for me ? :)
Any ideas would be welcome


Find people/companies who a) have money b) want the problem fixed and c) can't do it themselves
Persuade them that you are the right person to do the job at a price which works for both sides
Profit

I admit that probably isn't an easy sell, everybody using open source hopes that somebody else does the work and they get to take the benefits. xkcd 2347 is relevant here.

Well,I do have the company - my current workplace :)

But,I see that the problem is also relevant for a handful of other people/companies (At least according to messages in various mediums).How do I make paragragh 2 to them ?

Or alternatively,make it some kind of product , so I could sell to as much clients as possible?

@user426639, if your company would be a potential client, negotiate that you can make the fix in company time instead of your current project. For re-selling it to other companies, you could try to negotiate a split of the proceeds.
